# PHP Contact Form -- posting to email address/host part?

Tags: php, html

This is my first php and contact form coding/testing with the XAMPP. I'm very confused in which part of my contact.php should I insert the php script in order to send all the filled form to the my email address or XAMPP for the test? Should I create another php file or should I put the script inside the contact.php? 
These are all the files which are related to the contact.php.

1. contact.php (main sheet I've been working on)
2. validate.php (imported to contact.php ONLY to validate the form fields)
3. validate.js (functions in this file have been called in contact.php)

<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Contact.php >>>>>>>>>>>>>>

```
<body>
<div id="error">  
   <ul>  
   <?if(!validateName($_POST['name'])):?>  
      <li><strong>Invalid Name:</strong>Required more than 3 letters!</li>  
   <?endif?>  
   <?if(!validateSurname($_POST['surname'])):?>  
      <li><strong>Invalid Surname:</strong>Required more than 3 letters!</li>  
   <?endif?>  
   <?if(!validateEmail($_POST['email'])):?>  
      <li><strong>Invalid E-mail:</strong>Invalid email-address format!</li>  
   <?endif?>
   <?if(!validateMessage($_POST['message'])):?>  
      <li><strong>Invalid Message:</strong>Required more than 3 letters</li>  
   <?endif?>  
   <?if(!validateHuman($_POST['human'])):?>  
      <li><strong>Answer Incorrect:</strong>Human Validation Failed</li>  
   <?endif?>   
  </ul>  

</div> 

   <?elseif(isset($_POST['send'])):?>  
   <div id="error" class="valid">  
     <ul>  
       <li><strong>Congratulations!</strong></li>  
     </ul>  
   </div>  
   <?endif?>

<form method="post" id="customForm" action="????.php">
   .
   .
   .
<input id="send" name="send" type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/validation.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: You can add them on the top of the contact page.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it now can work.  Main issue right now is that regardless of whether the validations pass or not, you're going to display "Congratulations" because 'send' will always be set the way you are doing it.

The answers really depend on what you're trying to do.  If you're just submitting a form and telling the user, "hey, you submitted a form", then sure, this works.  But if you want it to do something more, then you may want to redirect a successful, validated post to a secondary page.

Comment: It's not working now as there's no script in any of those 3 files above, specifying WHERE or WHICH email account to send the form to. That's why I'm here, dispake.

Comment: Well, what I'm saying is that you can put that piece of code anywhere - all depends on what you might want to do.  If you simply want email, then sure, put the script in contacts since you already have all the post data there.  There really needs to be a greater goal if you want more detail.